# Using select function, piping and lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to use `lubridate` package along with the select function and piping provided in the `tidyverse` package for viewing the days in the dates. However, I cannot get it to work while using select. I thought I could use `select` instead of using the `$` operator. What is the problem here?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
> df <- data.frame(arrivals = c("2015-11-11","2015-11-12"))
> df$arrivals %>% day()
[1] 11 12
> df %>% select(arrivals) %>% day()
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df$arrivals` returns a vector whilst `df %>% select(arrivals)` returns a data.frame which `lubridate` apparently can't work with.

Using the `mutate` function instead gives the following:

```
> df %>% mutate(day(arrivals))
    arrivals day(arrivals)
1 2015-11-11            11
2 2015-11-12            12
```